# VLC is not installing the content menu

Tags: vlc-media-player, right-click

I tried twice installing VLC including the content menu (right click) option
However it is not appearing at the right click.
What can I do to include it?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: OS Version: Microsoft Windows 8.1, 64 bit
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz, Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3
Processor Count: 8
RAM: 12198 Mb
Graphics Card: AMD Radeon R9 M265X, -2048 Mb
Hard Drives: C: Total - 942989 MB, Free - 836632 MB;
Motherboard: TOSHIBA, VG20SQ

Comment: I don't know who down-voted this question, but I'm experiencing this same issue on Windows 7 64 bit running VLC 2.1.5 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the option "Set up associations" under Tools > Preferences > Interface > scroll down to "Set up associations" > click on it and select the list of file formats. Now check the content menu option availability.

[image]

Comment: I tried that but I get a Runtime error, BTW another thing that I was unable to solve!

Comment: If you get a runtime error there, then there's a good chance it's related to your problem.  Perhaps edit your question to include the actual Runtime error you receive (and when you receive it)?

Comment: sorry I don't know how to add an image here   Runtime Error!  Program: C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe  This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.   Please contact the application's support team for more information.  Indeed I could not find any clue in VLC website. Help appreciated...